# How to hide an element when JSON success returns less than specified number of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

EDIT: data.item needed to be data.length , also had a missing var

I need to hide the 'Get More' button if the JSON success data is less than 9 items and then check new responses and make it visible again if it is more than 9. I'm not too familiar with jQuery. So far the " if(data.item < 9) " is very wrong and I can't figure out the problem . Thanks for advice.

```
success: function(data) {
                        //console.log(data); //dump
                        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
                            $('#load-more-div').append('<div class="blogItem"> ' +item.date, item.title.rendered+ '<a href="'+item.link+'">Read More</a> </div>' ); 
                            $("#loading-image").hide(); //remove  gif                       

                            if ( data.item < 9 ) {// Remove the button if the response returns less than a full list of items
                            //loadMoreButton.remove();
                            document.getElementById("load-more").hide
                            }
                         }); //each          
                    } //success
```

Comment: What is data.item? Is it an array? Is it an int? The way you are using/describing I wanna say array but please confirm. The reason I ask is if it is an array or something you need the length.

Comment: @ZackaryJones document.getElementById isn't Jquery.  For vanilla document.getElementById you don't need a #.

Comment: oh duh, thank you for telling me that! (deleted original comment as it was not helpful)

Comment: @ZackaryJones dont mix jQuery with javascript

Comment: @basic I don't actually know, data.item was just a guess

Comment: @JoeBarrett Well that's your issue bud. You need to know what data type you are checking against. array < 9 is not the same as array.lenth < 9. You are treating data.item as an integer but what if it isn't? Do a console.log on item and edit the question with the output.

Comment: **item.title, item.rendered** is not OK - the comma between them is not an operator here.

Comment: @basic turns out, the var for loadmoreButton was not inside the function so i moved it up and it is fixed. and it needed to be  data.length < 9 thanks for the extra eyes, i have  a lot to learn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think **data.length** is the number.

**data.item.length** is always going to return 1, as it’s inside the **$.each()** (OK, if it’s an array it may return something else)

So, your code should be

```
if ( data.length < 9 ) {
    // your code here
} else {
    // do something, like unhide the items
}
```

And you can take it out from the **$.each()** as you don’t need to check it for each **item** in **data**

Comment: Thank you, this helped. Also I had a var outside where it needed to be.

Comment: Happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without fully understanding what `data.item` is, I added a `.length` to the end of it, which should give you length, in terms of an integer, that you are  looking for.

```
success: function(data) {
   //console.log(data); //dump
   $.each(data, function(index, item) {
     $('#load-more-div').append('<div class="blogItem"> ' +item.date, item.title.rendered+ '<a href="'+item.link+'">Read More</a> </div>' ); 
     $("#loading-image").hide(); //remove  gif                       
     if ( data.length < 9 ) {// Remove the button if the response returns less than a full list of items
       //loadMoreButton.remove();
       document.getElementById("load-more").hide
     }
   }); //each          
} //success
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the original code. What should I add to help the question be more clear?

Comment: Hey @JoeBarrett - next time add what `data.item` is. I've modified my answer to fit the type of data (`data` === array)